# How to insert first map's data to another map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Here is my code:

```
void Schedule::studentSchedule()
{
    string c,s;
    int courseNum;
    list<string>::iterator studentLoc; // this is my student list. I am searching s from this list.
    map<string,map<string,pair<string,Array> > >::iterator last;//first string s = student name,second string c=course name,third string day,Array type = day hours
    map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,Array> >::iterator location;//first string c= course name,second string day,Array type = day hours
    //What I want to do is gets the data from location iterator's map(getMatchMap()) and insert the last iterator's map.(getCourseScList())

    dummy1:
    cout<<"Enter the student name"<<endl;
    cin >> s;
    cout<<"Enter the course names you want"<<endl;
    cin>>c;
    auto predicate = [&](auto& course) { return compareName(course, c); };
    studentLoc = find(getStudentList().begin(),getStudentList().end(),s);
    location = find_if(getMatchMap().begin(), getMatchMap().end(), predicate);

    if(studentLoc != getStudentList().end() || location != getMatchMap().end())
    {
        getCourseScList().insert(s,{c,{}});
        //How can I get the same data when I input the course name. I mean how can I get the data from getMatchMap() 
        //with the same information
    }
```

I commented the code as possible i can.

For example :

If I had a Programming course data like this in the matchMap map :

```
Programming ---> Monday ---> 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

How can I get the data to courseScList(getCourseScList()):

```
'Student name I enter' ---> Programming --> Monday ---> 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert first map's data to another when the user enter a value which is in the first map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59546002/how-to-insert-first-maps-data-to-another-when-the-user-enter-a-value-which-is-i)

Comment: Please don't re-post your questions. Instead, edit and improve the old question. It'll get nominated to be reopen and thrown into the queue to be looked at by other users so they can vote on it.

Comment: I editted the question but it's closed. They say:  `Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one.`